# Cannot re-define @font-size-h* in Twitter Bootstrap using LESS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

My `style.less` imports Bootstrap 3 `.less` files and then customize some variables in order to output `style.css`:

```
@bs-less: "../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less";

// Core variables and mixins
@import "@{bs-less}/variables.less";
@import "@{bs-less}/mixins.less";

// Core CSS
@import "@{bs-less}/type.less";

// Customizations
@font-family-sans-serif:  "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
@font-size-base: 18px; // override working
@font-size-h1:  floor(@font-size-base * 5); // originally 2.6 (46px) changed to 5
```

Customizing the `@font-size-base` variable works fine as `@font-family-sans-serif`.

The problem I'm getting is with `@font-size-h1` (more generally with `@font-size-h*`), which is completely ignored, i.e 46px but should be around 90px. I changed the multiplication from 2.6 to 5.

I'm just start learning LESS, is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**: in `type.less` variable `@font-size-h1` is actually used:

```
h1, .h1 { font-size: @font-size-h1; }
```

Comment: Also notice: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#accessibility (nested headers)

Comment: Have you tried putting your customizations before your `Core CSS` import? It really _should not make a difference in LESS_, but I am curious if by chance it resolves your issue. From what I can tell, your code should be working.

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-sizer: 10;
.test(@fs){font-size:@fs*5px;}
h1{.test(@font-sizer)}
@font-sizer: 20;
```

It seems the results depends on your compiler. Less compilers have different precedence rules maybe?

The above results with lessc 1.4.2 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript] in: `h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}` alhought i can find a reason (unambiguous rule) why the result should not be `h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}`

Also see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8947

Comment: As to why your answer result is `100px` and not `50px`, it is because the second `@font-sizer` is what takes precedence (overriding the first), so the call inside the `h1` is equal to `.test(20)`. This is how LESS works, the variables are overridden regardless of code sequence. That is, the `@font-sizer` is overridden before the `h1` mixin call is ever made, even though the `h1` code is "before" the second `@font-sizer` in the code, it is not "before" it in operation of calculation. All variables are resolved first.

Comment: @ScottS yes thanks, i understood. Where do i find the documentation of  this precedence?

Comment: i.e. there's no any "precedence" as such, the last variable definition always overrides any prev. definitions in the same scope. See also [Last Declaration Win](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Variables#last-declaration-win---even-after-use).

Comment: thanks, so i did learn a lot. After reading this stuff i still don't understand the results of @gremo